# How to get selected checkboxes items from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

I have a listbox where the items contain checkBoxes:
I want to get string `Content` for every CheckBox that user selected

```
            <ListBox Name="SendCodecsNamelistBox"
                     Height="52"
                     Margin="150,128,31,65"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=.}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: What is it bound to?  It's probably better to get the information you need from the datasource that backs the UI, rather than getting it from the UI directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a model like this

```
public class Model
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and bind it to the checkbox

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Content}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        var data = new List<Model>()
        {
            new Model{ Content = "item1", IsSelected = false},
            new Model{ Content = "item2", IsSelected = false},
            new Model{ Content = "item1", IsSelected = false},
            new Model{ Content = "item3", IsSelected = false}
        };

        SendCodecsNamelistBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

Then you can get what you want like this

```
var selectedContents = data.Where(i => i.IsSelected)
                           .Select(i => i.Content)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why WPF and MVVM are coupled together. Because you can put anything in the `ItemsTemplate`, to get info about checked items directly from GUI is a pain.

Bind your `ListBox` to the collection of view models having `IsChecked` property, than bound that property to `CheckBox.IsChecked` and you will get checked items from collection.